# Can't set default value

Tags: forms, drupal

Using  drupal 7 I try to render only one field. Code:

```
$form = array();
$form['pager2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('page'),
    '#options' => array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2'), 
    '#default_value' => '2',
);
$page.=drupal_render($form);
```

Default value in any case is '1'. What i've done wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Try out below code:

```
$form = array();
$form['pager2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('page'),
    '#options' => array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2'), 
    '#default_value' => '2',
);
return $form;
```